# Deploying the angular project on GitHub pages

Tags: angular, github, web-deployment, github-pages

We are just started building an angular project,and im just a normal user on GitHub,i want to deploy the initial webApp in the github pages,i want to know how to do so and on future we will be changing the site can it be updated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you searched for it first? https://pages.github.com/ Do you have a specific problem with it?

Comment: Ya, only the readme file deployed